# Hit area is only on label of UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibutton, cgrect

I create a UIButton like this:

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
```

The button works, but the hit area is only on the text, not the entire button. I've set the background of the button to be `[UIColor clearColor]`. What do I need to do to make it so that the entire frame of the button is the hit area?

I suppose I could change the frame of the label to equal the button, but that seems hokey. Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you adding a UILabel to the button?

Comment: Moxy, no just using the stock button.  My assumption is that it's a UILabel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button in question was being built up with layers.  What I ended up doing was ensuring the background layer had a solid background color.  Simply setting the background of the button to  clear did not work in this case.

```
//set a background color so it is clickable
[layer0 setBackgroundColor: CGCOLORA(0, 1) ];
```

Comment: Ah, that's because transparent layers don't respond to touches.  Adding `button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];` fixed this for me.

Answer (score 2):

try like this,

```
        UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
        button.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [button setTitle:@"Set" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the opaque property of the UIButton to true worked for me (iOS10)